# Problems creating Windows Store app. (Windows 8)

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps

When i create a new Blank App (XAML) Project in Visual studio i get these errors:

Starts of with some references are incorrect. Should it really be like this in a new solution? (havn't written anything yet)
If i try to build at this Point i get :

> Cannot resolve Windows Metadata

So i figured i'll fix the namespace issues.
This was by adding reference to Window and add namespace `Windows.UI.XAML`;
After that i get over 3000 (3136) errors here is some of them :

> - The .winmd file 'Windows.winmd' contains type 'Windows.Globalization.ILanguageStatics'. The use of the Windows
>     namespace is reserved.
> - The .winmd file 'Windows.winmd' contains type
>     'Windows.Globalization.ICalendarFactory'. The use of the Windows
>     namespace is reserved.
> - The .winmd file 'Windows.winmd' contains type 'Windows.Globalization.IGeographicRegion'. The use of the Windows namespace is reserved.
> - The .winmd file 'Windows.winmd' contains type 'Windows.Globalization.DayOfWeek'. The use of the Windows namespace is reserved.
> - etc.

**What i've tried so far**

- Repair Visual Studio
- Repair SDK'
- Uninstall/Reinstall the SDK'

' [Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852363.aspx)

I should also add that i've upgraded my Windows 7 to Windows 8.

Anyone has any suggestions about how to solve this issue?

Comment: Re-installing windows 8 was what i did. :(

Comment: Hopefully i can find a solution before i choose that aproach.. But it seems like there is a error in the installation..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A co-worker had a similar problem with his references. Although, he was on Win 7 and not Win 8. What he did was reinstall the Windows 8 SDK.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852363.aspx

Might worth an attempt before doing the whole Win 8.

Comment: +1 @Grigmin Thanks for the tip. Actually i've uninstalled the current, downloaded a new and installed that again. I'll try a repair tomorrow, feels like it's something with the installation somehow.

Comment: Forgot to update you on this. But it didn't work out for me. =(

Comment: Guess i'll go with the complete reinstall of Windows 8.. =/

Comment: did re-installation solves your problem ?? i am having same issue

Comment: @Arun Yes it did. But check notacat's post, and see if that can help you out before reinstalling. =)

Comment: i try notacat solution, but every-time you change code it recreate the winmd i found it is due to another dll i use for implementing mvvm i.e. Galasoft.light.win8 :(

Answer (score 5):

I just hit against this issue with VS 2012 Update 2. There were one more warning in the output, something like "can't find implementation details for the 'Windows.winmd' file" (I didn't save this text, so don't remember exact spelling. This warning pointed to the Windows.winmd in some project Debug folder. I found that this folder actually contained the copy of this file. Apparently, VS made this copy for some reason. After removing it I was able to build my projects again.

So, read all warnings before reinstalling SDK, VS or Windows 8

Comment: +1 I cleaned the solution, then did a search of the solution directory for any instances of "Windows.winmd" and deleted those. Then my solution built correctly.

Answer (score 4):

I had a common portable project being shared across a number of ports. To fix the issue I located the Windows reference and changed Copy Local to False. Has been fine since.